# How do you get the regex match group in ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to be able modify the match based on which group it belongs to in ruby. Something like below:

```
def splitter(m)  
  if match == 1
    return m+"\n"
  elsif match == 2
    return m+"\t"
  elsif match == 3
    return "\n"+m    
end

s = "0 1 2 3"
s.gsub(/(1)|(2)|(3)/) {|m| splitter(m)}
```

s should result in

```
"0 1\n 2\t \n3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are much easier ways to do what you wish to, yet this might be OK to look at:

```
re = /(1)|(2)|(3)/
str = '0 1 2 3'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s

    match.each { |x| puts x}

    if match.include?('1') 
        puts 'return 1'
    end
    if match.include?('2')
        puts 'return 1'
    end
    if match.include?('3')
        puts 'return 3'
    end
end
```

#### Output

```
["1", nil, nil]
1


return 1
[nil, "2", nil]

2

return 1
[nil, nil, "3"]


3
return 3
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. but what if the match is not as obvious such as 1, 2, 3...  i need to be able to target the group specifically

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\d` instead of `(1)(2)(3)`, and matched word is a string so you need to compare with string whereas were comparing with number

```
def splitter(match) 
  if match == "1"
    return match+"\n";
  elsif match == "2"
    return match+"\t";
  elsif match == "3"
    return "\n"+match;
 else return match;
end;
end;
s = "0 1 2 3";
l = s.gsub(/\d/) {|m| splitter(m)};
print l;
```

[`Ruby Demo`](https://repl.it/@VivekJain1/Rubm-match-digits)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the regex /(1)|(2)|(3)/ is just an example to simplify my question... the regex for each group is more complicated for my situation and I must be able to target each matching group specifically

Comment: @echan00 You can access using `match[0]` and so on